# Não estou conseguindo resolver o seguinte erro no meu navigator

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Home'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when importing.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
```

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import Tabs from './src/navigation/tabs'
import Stacks from './src/navigation/stacks'

const App = () =>  {
return (




)
}
export default App;

stck.js

```
import React from 'react'
```

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { StartScreen } from '../screens/StartScreen';
import { LoginScreen } from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import { RegisterScreen } from '../screens/RegisterScreen';
import { ResetPasswordScreen } from '../screens/ResetPasswordScreen';
import { HomeScreen } from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

const Stacks = () => {
return (
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="StartScreen" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false,}}>
<Stack.Screen name="Start" component={StartScreen} />
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
<Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
<Stack.Screen name="Reset" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />

```
      </Stack.Navigator> 
);
```

}
export default Stacks;

tabs.js

```
import React from 'react'
```

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { HomeScreen } from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import { PesquisaScreen } from '../screens/PesquisaScreen';
import { ChatScreen } from '../screens/ChatScreen';
import { PerfilScreen } from '../screens/PerfilScreen';
import { ProdutoScreen } from '../screens/ProdutoScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
return (

```
    <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Pesquisa" component={PesquisaScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Perfil" component={PerfilScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Produto" component={ProdutoScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

}
export default Tabs;

Answer (score -1):

A versão do seu React-Navigation é a 5x ?

React Navigation passou por uma atualização e atualmente está na versão 6x.

Então você pode adicionar o seguinte comando.

```
yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

yarn add @react-navigation/native-stack
```

A lib modificou um pouco e ficará da seguinte forma.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Assim você conseguirá utilizar no seu projeto. Qualquer eventual erro, pode pontuar que acompanharei o tópico.